# Elif not being recognized in PyCharm (Python)

Tags: python, if-statement, pycharm, statements

Need help with if else statements. Everytime I run it the elif is not being recognized.

```
Wday = 17 

Wtues = 12 

Wend = 20 

day = input("Input the day of the drama: ") 
num = int(input("How many tickets? ")) 

if day == "monday" or "wednesday" or "thursday" or "friday":
    print(f"Total ticket cost is = ${num * Wday}") 
elif day == "tuesday": 
    print(f"Total ticket cost is = ${num * Wtues}") 
elif day == "sunday" or "saturday": 
    print(f"Total ticket cost is = ${num + Wend}")
else:
    print("Invalid.")
    exit()
```

The result when I run it is:

Input the day of the drama: Tuesday

How many tickets? 1

Total ticket cost is = $17

(The answer should be $12 not $17)

Comment: the first "if" line is equivalent to `if (day == "monday") or bool("wednesday") or bool("thursday") or ...` and `bool("non-empty string")` is always true, so the line is basically `if False or True or True or True`

Comment: Python is not English.  `if day == "monday" or day == "wednesday"`, etc. is required, not `if day == "monday" or "wednesday"`.  You can use `if day in ("monday", "wednesday, "thursday", friday")` however.

Comment: Your comparison is wrong, your are comparing "Tuesday" with "tuesday". Add a line ```day.lower()``` to put the input data in lowercase.

Comment: add `day = str(input("Input the day of the drama: ")).lower()`, and turn to if statements `day == ("monday" or "wednesday" or "thursday" or "friday")`